# How to repeat the sound clip to the entire length of the video clip?

Tags: audio, imovie, garageband

As you can see in my screen shot

[image]

I have a movie clip that is much longer than the auto clip. The audio clip is just some generic background music created in Garage Band.

I would like to keep repeat the audo clip until the end of the video clip. However I cannot find a way to do it.

Some suggested to manually copy and past the audio clip, but it is time consuming and error prone. Is there a better way to make the clip loop by itself.

I don't mind if the a solution can be achieved on the Garage Band side.

Comment: Doesn't garage-band let you drag the end of the audio to any length, and loop the audio to fill the remaining space? You know how long the video clip is, so drag the audio to be that length in Garageband.